# Node.js + sequelize + express transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js, acid

Hy, i'm new to nodejs and sequelize world (coming from java + spring).
And i have a question about how transactions as used in nodejs and sequelize. I can make this works with a transaction in a controller and use the continuation-local-storage module, something like that:

```
router.post('/client/new', function (req, res, next) {
    models.sequelize.transaction({
        autocommit: false
    }, function (t) {
        function insertClient(company) {
            var body = _.extend({}, req.body);
            body.id_company = company.id;
            return models.Client.create(body);
        }

        return models.Company.find({
            where: {
                id: req.body.company.id
            }
        }).then(function (company) {
            if (company) {
                return insertClient(company);
            } else {
                return models.Company.create(nome: req.body.company).then(function (company) {
                    return insertClient(company);
                });
            }
        });
    }).then(function (client) {
        return res.json({
            client: client
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        next(err);
    });
});
```

But this way have a problem, if the client connection aborted when download the body the commit was already made. Has any way i can do that when the request finish? Or how is the best way to do that ?
Has any other REST or ORM framework that can do something like that ? (Commit on finish of the request)

Thanks for your time a and patience.

Comment: IMHO, [LoopBack](http://loopback.io/) - best choice for make REST API. It also has built-in Juggler ORM

Comment: I will look at that, thank your